# Шансы в javascript

Tags: javascript

Как реализовать шансы? Например, `3` выводится в консоль с шансом 30%, в остальных случаях `4`. Конечно, можно создать массив с "тройками" и "четверками", с помощью `Math.random` и `Math.floor` получать число от 1 до 100, и выводить *соответствующий индекс массива + 1*. Но это не практично.

Comment: можно сгенерить случайное значение от 0 до 1 и если оно будет меньше 0.3 то выводить 3, в остальных случаях 4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
function getRandom3or4() {
  return Math.random() < 0.3? 3 : 4;
}

var count3 = 0, count4 = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
  getRandom3or4() == 3? count3++ : count4++;
}

console.log(count3, count4);
```

Comment: *тот случай когда коммент текстом пишешь дольше чем код :D